What was the meaning of this unusual version of "natural" in the early 1970's?
I just want to say off the bat that I can speculate really well myself, was culturally adjacent, and am pretty good with the language. So if you don't have more or novel information on this subject than I have, you probably don't have an answer I'm looking for.
I was born in the late 1960's. That means for a lot of 1970's lingo I was wasn't really participating in the culture, but I was adjacent enough to it that I could pick it up from context. For example, I know what "groovy" meant.
However, there's one term that I've been at a loss to figure out the meaning of for the last 50 years: "natural". I know what it means today (basically the opposite of "artificial"). However, its pretty clear there was a different meaning, used in a different context, in the early 1970's. I'll give a couple of examples:

dancing in the moonlight 
everybody's feeling warm and bright its such a
fine and natural sight everybody's dancing in the moonlight


Dancing in the Moonlight, written in 1970.


Sweet, sweet Connie, doin' her act She had the whole show and that's a
natural fact


American Band, released in 1973.

I'm pretty sure there are more I've stumbled across over the years, but these are the two I easily remember.
Now I'm pretty sure this form of the word is being used as an intensifier. That probably explains why its so tough for me to suss out any further meaning from it via context. However, I don't think its a completely general intensifier.
I'm hoping someone can come in here with answers that rely on one (or more) of 3 things:

More examples, that allow us to better triangulate this term's early 1970's meaning.
First hand knowledge as someone who was the right age (probably between 60 and 70 now) to report how this was actually used and what was meant when it was used.
Some reference to someone else doing one of the above.


@ishtar - Dang good catch. It looks like that song was written by Oliver Leiber. If google is to be believed (diecy now that it uses AI), he's 7 years older than me, meaning he would in fact have been old enough to internalize its meaning in the early 1970's.

The Google Ngram graph for "natural fact" indicates that the term has been in use for more than 250 years, and that it has grown substantially more frequent in published writing since the early 1970s, though it has still not attained the pinnacle of frequency that it reached in 1878.

I don't think it's an intensifier. It has its normal meaning of not something created by humans. But in many contexts that implies that it's better, because it's unsullied by human interference (similar to the way we think "organic" produce is better).

You make me feel like a natural woman. Alone again naturally. Come dancing, it's only natural. I'll refrain from speculation, as instructed.

In folksy usage. "a natural fact" came to be used rather like  "a fact of life" and "the unvarnished truth". You find it in so-called "Negro Spirituals" dating from the days of slavery and collected in the first decades of the 20th century by folklorists. I think the second lyric is using it in that manner: She had the whole show and that's a natural fact.  I don't think that's an attestation of how the word "natural" was used in the sixties.

@StuartF - I don't think the Come Dancing example counts, as its being used as a nominalized adjective there, and makes perfect sense with the typical modern definition of the word. The first one though is definitely using it as an intensifier. The second is another common usage of the word (sort of a "yes, and this should be expected" or "of course") that's still in modern usage AFAIK.

Fact of nature, sight in nature... OED: “I.1. Existing or present by nature; inherent in the very constitution of a person or thing; innate; not acquired or assumed.” Also throwing “naturals” — natural hairdo’s — into the mix here.

@TinfoilHat - Disagree. I know what "natural" means in every one of those sentences in the examples of that section (and know what different thing it would mean without that word). If you wanna peruse the OED for definitions, instead look down around 1.7 to 1.9, particularly 1.8.a (which it says is obsolete). See the comments in ermanem's answer below.

I fail to see how a sight or a fact could be [I.8.a.] Having innate abilities and gifts. [Obsolete. rare.]

A fine and natural sight, like a natural vibe, impromptu but familiar. Gets you in the feels. Not like disco (for show) or snaking (LSD? IDK).

I think it simply means simple. Natural can be used for something real or genuine; free from nonsense or pretention. OED lists this sense connected to   the nature with the earliest citation from 1553 as below:

Of thought, behaviour, or expression: having the ease or simplicity of nature; free from affectation, artificiality, or constraint; simple, unaffected, easy.
1553 If proper and naturall wordes, in well ioyned sentences do lyuely expresse the matter. 
R. Ascham, Report Affaires Germany 1
Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “natural (adj.), sense I.10.a,” June 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1078228393.


The OED entru has a few more recent citations that are more persuasive

@Mari-LouA - If so I'd like to see them, as I have to confess to being less than fully persuaded by this one.

@T.E.D. it's in the link. 1971 The charm and humility of his essentially natural personality. (1.10.b) Meg liked men natural, she'd claimed once, not reeking with male perfumes. 1973 (1.11.a)

@Mari-LouA - That is in fact quite helpful. Unfortunately for this answer however, of the meanings listed, the one being referred to here  (1.10.a if I'm reading things right) is one of the least applicable. Far better would be the meanings from 1.7-1.9, although I don't think any of them are quite there either. The (supposedly extinct) Scottish one in 1.8.a seems closest. Notice every example in there has it used as an intensifier of some kind.

Now that I think about it, this wouldn't be the first time a word or term the O.E.D. claimed was extinct popped up much later in an AmE dialect, would it?

@T.E.D. I don't see how other definitions you've mentioned are closer in meaning and this is the least applicable. I've read through all senses and this is the most applicable one (which can be used both for people and things, including abstract things also), considering the citations as well.

Dancing in the Moonlight is an example of how "natural" came to be associated with "getting back to nature". Civilization was seen as suffering from a kind of illness that only a return to nature would cure.
Compare this lyric from Joni Mitchell:

And we've got to get ourselves
Back to the garden


All good. And Joni's garden was Eden.

@YosefBaskin ... as mentioned later in CSN's "Woodstock" and GnR's "Lost in the Garden of Eden"

Not to mention Iron Butterfly's "In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida"
